# NullPointerException in onActivityResult after calling camera intent

Tags: android, camera

Here's my problem: I need to save photo to default camera location, than copy it to my private location, add GPS tags to copy, and delete original photo. Why so around? Because on some devices, when using `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` in request intent photo was saved in default location anyway. Now when application was nearly complete, when testing on new device (Motorola MB526) it crushes after accepting taken picture. Same thing happens on emulator.

The thing is, that in `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` `data.getData()` returns null.

So my question is - Is there any unified way to save picture in given location and nowhere else?

**EDIT:**

capture image intent

```
protected void takePhotos() {
    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                Uri capturedImageUri = data.getData();
                Log.d("cameraResult", "data =" + data.getDataString());
                String capturedPicFilePath = getRealPathFromURI(capturedImageUri);
                writeImageData(capturedImageUri, capturedPicFilePath);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Picture not taken",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Picture not taken",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] projx = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, contentUri, projx,
                null, null, null);
        cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    } else {
        cursor = this.managedQuery(contentUri, projx, null, null, null);
    }
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

logCat output:

```
07-23 18:42:26.486: D/cameraResult(1744): data =null
07-23 18:42:26.486: D/AndroidRuntime(1744): Shutting down VM
07-23 18:42:26.486: W/dalvikvm(1744): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb70334f0)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1513, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {arios.e_gps/arios.e_gps.photos.PhotoListAct}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at arios.e_gps.photos.PhotoListAct.getRealPathFromURI(PhotoListAct.java:316)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at arios.e_gps.photos.PhotoListAct.onActivityResult(PhotoListAct.java:165)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
07-23 18:42:26.496: E/AndroidRuntime(1744):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: `onActivityResult()` doesn't return null because it doesn't return anything. Post your full logcat and relevant code

Comment: Not onActivityResult() - inside it, `data.getData()` returns null.

Comment: Your NPE is at `arios.e_gps.photos.PhotoListAct.getRealPathFromURI(PhotoListAct.java:316)`... Also why are you using managed queries? `Loader` is in the support lib, you don't need that extra code.

Comment: Yes it's in `getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)`. It is caused, by `contentUri` being null. It's null because `getData()` returns null.

I found that solution while ago, when searching for cure for photos saved in two locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

It's probably wrong but i did this to get uri after ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE and it works for me.

```
        Bitmap picture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), picture,
                "title" , null);
        Uri uriPhoto = Uri.parse(path);
```

Comment: I've misspelled first line of logcat output.
`Log.d("cameraResult", "data =" + data.getDataString());` results with `07-23 18:42:26.486: D/cameraResult(1744): data =null` in logcat.
I know it shouldn't be null there, but it is...

Comment: Looks like it did the trick. Now I just need to get rid of those photos from gallery.

Answer (score 3):

Data.getData() is not null when requesting a thumbnail. When recording a picture to any location it will always be null.